# Duplicate functions in a module and changing a default argument

Tags: python, python-2.7

I struggling to find a solution which would duplicate functions, rename it and apply an argument. An example is more illustrative

I have a module with:

```
get(a, c=4, ver=False):
  ...

set(a, b, c=4, ver=False):
  ...
```

etc

and would like to create for all these functions corresponding functions if done by hand

```
ver_get(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['ver'] = True
    return get(*args, **kwargs)

ver_set(*args, **kwargs):
    kwargs['ver'] = True
    return set(*args, **kwargs)
```

I have tried a for loop over all the functions, but failed due to the late binding issue of f (see below). I could not apply the normal workaround with supplying the function f as an input due to the use of *args, **kwargs.

```
funcs = {}
g = None
f = None
for g, f in globals().iteritems():
    funcs['ver_'+g] = lambda *args, **kwargs: f(*args, **dict(kwargs, ver=True))
```

After this funcs would also need to be included in globals.

Why do I want to do this? Just to have a better syntax without needing to duplicate the functions manually.

Answer (score 0):

I tried to find an answer earlier but failed, then suddenly I tripped over it. Use partial. Complete solution:

```
funcs = {}
g = None
f = None
from functools import partial
for g, f in globals().iteritems():
    if hasattr(f, '__call__'):
        funcs['ver_'+g] = partial(f, ver=True)
globals().update(funcs)
del funcs
del g
del f
```